# Amazon SQS service failure.Mule message not delivered to VM queue

Tags: mule, mule-studio, amazon-sqs, cloudhub, anypoint-studio

I have a simple flow which put orders in a dlq which is an VM connector.But suddenly I got an exception as below

```
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=vm://dlq, connector=VMConnector
{
  name=VM1
  lifecycle=start
  this=5b97228a
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[vm]
  serviceOverrides=
}
,  name='endpoint.vm.dlq', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 503; Error Code: null; Request ID: null) (com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException)
  com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient:1073 (null)
```

Can anyone clarify what has went wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing your running this on Cloudhub. On Cloudhub persistent VM queues are backed by Amazon SQS queues. Why the error occured, could be there was an issue with AWS or as it states here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/2009-02-01/APIReference/index.html?Query_QueryErrors.html maybe the requests have been throttled due to too high a throughput.

Comment: "On Cloudhub persistent VM queues are backed by Amazon SQS queues" Thanks this what I was searching for.Thanks a lot